# Azure service bus messages intermittently unauthorized despite using correct shared access signature values...why?

Tags: django, azure, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a django application that routinely injects messages into an Azure service bus.  I am receiving intermittent errors indicating that its messages are unauthorized.  I would say that 95% of messages are successfully authorized, with about 5% unauthorized).

I have not changed anything in months related to access (shared access signatures, access keys etc) to the service bus, and I have validated that my python code is still using all the correct values (service bus namespace, topic, access key, etc).

Despite this, I am receiving intermittent errors related to having an invalid authorization token signature:
"AzureHttpError('SubCode=40103: Invalid authorization token signature',)`

How can I correct this, and how can I find out the cause?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas), the token is generated using a few things:

```
SharedAccessSignature sig=<signature-string>&se=<expiry>&skn=<keyName>&sr=<URL-encoded-resourceURI>
```

You said you've checked the access key, so maybe you should check is your time on your server/computer/device has a correct and stable clock.

For debugging you can just write a log before the service bus call to print the current timestamp of your server and work out whether it is correct.